# What is this socket name and where can I buy the female counterpart?

Tags: connector, identification, jtag

I have this socket on a PCB which is half inch wide (1.27 centimeters) with pins being close together (I think 0.05") and not uniformly spaced like in a normal IDC connector.
I need to create a ribbon cable from 6-pin JTAG to this socket: what is this socket name and where can I buy the female counterpart?

[image]

[image]

(pics from a 3D model)

Comment: I think that is ICDI Connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like its from the SHF series from SAMTEC -> [2x5 with 1.27mm grid](http://uk.farnell.com/samtec/shf-105-01-l-d-th-tr/header-1-27mm-2x5way/dp/2416477)

[image]

What do you mean with "not uniformly spaced like in a normal IDC connector"?

EDIT: [SAMTEC's counterpart connector](http://uk.farnell.com/samtec/ffsd-05-01-n/connector-receptacle-idc-1-27mm/dp/1753841)

Comment: I think they're referring to the gaps on either side of the pins - the pins aren't uniformly spaced within the socket area.

Comment: Exactly. This looks exactly like my socket, but it's hard for me to find a cable connector/header for this type of sockets since they all appear to be without side gaps

Comment: That's a WhiteNoise\$^{TM}\$ connector, every pin "is guaranteed to have its x and y coordinates randomly chosen obeying a gaussian distribution within the connector area"

Comment: @Vlad I LOL'd but I'm not a hardware guy, finding the right connector is driving me crazy x_x

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna didn't mean to make fun of you... Spero che non ti sia offeso ;)

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna: Looking at the part description from SAMTEC, it wasn't hard to find the counterpart connector. I added a link.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an IDC connector:

They are available from everywhere
https://www.futurlec.com/ConnIDC.shtml

http://www.digikey.com/product-highlights/us/en/assmann-electronics-idc-connectors-cables/2137

http://www.pololu.com/product/855

Probably 50mil spacing.

Comment: Clearly not 100 mil spacing, given the pins next to it. Probably 50 mil spacing.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast true, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is called a *shrouded header*.

Unfortunately there are many different varieties made by many different manufacturers.  The first thing to do is measure the pin pitch.  That will be the easiest parameter to limit searches on different manufacturer web sites.  After that, you just have to look around to see who has exactly that pattern of external dimension, extra bumps, and notches.  Every connector manufacturer will make something close, but you need to look at the details of the housing (the shroud) carefully to see if what you find really matches.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: It would be useful to explain what exactly you think is wrong, misleading, badly worded, etc.  I realize I didn't give a definative answer, but I think still some useful information for the OP.